# How to trigger select change event from custom placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I have custom placeholder above select control. but the click event is not triggering when I click the custom placeholder, please suggest the best way to achive the select event, with out using jquery.

[image]

Please check the code

```html
<div id='placeholder'  style='font-size:10px; dispaly:none;background-color:red;position:absolute;left:10px'>
Options
</div>

<select id='selectcontrol' style='background-color:yellow; height:40px'>
<option>Option A</option>
<option>Option B</option>
<option>Option C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need to trigger a specific event when choosing a select?

Comment: I dont want to triger any specific event, when clicking placeholer the select open was not working, with firatozcevahir answer, I'm able to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can wrap your `select` and `placeholder div` with another div.
- Make `select`'s background transparent
- Make sure that your `placeholder div` is below the `select` using `position:absolute` for both of the elements

```html
<div style="background-color:yellow;height:40px;width:100px">
  <div id='placeholder' style='font-size:10px;background-color:red;position:absolute;left:10px'>
    Options
  </div>
  <select id='selectcontrol' style='background-color:transparent; height:inherit;width:inherit;position:absolute;'>
    <option>Option A</option>
    <option>Option B</option>
    <option>Option C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```